# What is block.coinbase in solidity?

Tags: solidity, smart-contract

I am not able to understand what this keyword exactly does. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> block.coinbase (address payable): current block miner’s address

https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.19/units-and-global-variables.html#block-and-transaction-properties

Answer (score -1):

`block.coinbase` is a global variable in Solidity that represents the address of the miner who mined the block in which the current contract execution is included.

The block object is a global variable in Solidity that provides information about the current block, such as its number (block.number), timestamp (block.timestamp), and difficulty (block.difficulty). The block.coinbase variable specifically refers to the address of the miner who mined the block.

This variable can be useful in smart contracts that involve mining or proof-of-work consensus mechanisms. For example, a contract might award a certain amount of tokens to the miner of the current block, or it might require the miner to perform some additional computation in order to receive a reward.

View functions in Ethereum are functions that do not change the state of the blockchain and are executed locally on the node that is making the request. When a view function is executed, it has access to the current state of the blockchain, including the current block's coinbase address.

So, when a view function returns block.coinbase, it is simply returning the value of the coinbase address of the current block that is already part of the blockchain state. The view function does not need to be included in the block itself, as it is only accessing the information that is already stored on the blockchain.

In summary, a view function can return block.coinbase even though it is not added to the block because it is accessing information that is already part of the blockchain state, and view functions do not modify the blockchain state themselves.

Comment: Alright. But what if I create a view function to just return the `block.coinbase`. I am not executing any transaction in the chain. What will the function or `block.coinbase` return at that moment?

Comment: View functions in Ethereum are functions that do not change the state of the blockchain and are executed locally on the node that is making the request. When a view function is executed, it has access to the current state of the blockchain, including the current block's coinbase address.

In summary, a view function can return `block.coinbase` even though it is not added to the block because it is accessing information that is already part of the blockchain state, and view functions do not modify the blockchain state themselves.

Comment: Using ChatGPT and other predictive technology for answering questions is forbidden.